# I2C bus slave powered before raspberry pi master

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, rtc

I have a number of I2C slaves (PCF85063AT) connected a Raspberry Pi, which acts as master. For various reasons the I2C slaves are powered at all times, where the power to the Pi can be controlled on/off. Everytime I connect the system to power, the Raspberry Pi does not detect the PCF85063AT during boot. I can see it from the i2cdetect, but the driver does not load it initally during boot. To proper detect it I need the system to do a reboot.

When the systems are on different power sources (but share same common ground), do I need to add a I2C line buffer or what seems to be the issue here?

Thanks.

Comment: Which power source pull up the two I2C resistors? Perhaps it should be the RPi's Vdd.

Comment: If you can't find a simple hardware solution, you could probably easily patch the Linux driver to do a second try if the first one fails.

Comment: 1) The two pull up resistors are connected to the same power source as the slaves, so the constant one. 
2) Patching the linux kernal could be a solution. But I have a coincell battery connected to the PCF85063AT (like in the CM4io datasheet) and the RTC should remember the clock at all times and resetting the device would also reset the clock (to my knowledge).

Comment: RPi is supposed to have onboard pull-ups to 3V3, if this is the case why there are external pull-ups too to always-on 3V3? Also resetting the bus does not mean resetting the RTC, only a sequence to clear the bus and all components on it to a known state.

Comment: So the external pull ups could be the issue, I'll check that. But why does it work after a reboot of the RPi?

Comment: The slave is probably catching spurious edges on SCL/SDA during powerup of the Raspberry Pi, for whatever reason. This puts its I2C state machine into a bad state, so it misses whatever probe command the Linux driver is sending it. I2C is somewhat self-healing with start and stop conditions, so after a reboot there has been enough I2C activity to resynchronize the slave's state machine so it can be probed. Look into "I2C bus recovery." Without a hardware change you'll need to get Linux to generate some I2C traffic or do a bus revovery sequence before the probe.

Comment: There could be number of reasons it works after a reboot. We'd need to see the bus transactions captured with a logic analyzer or oscilloscope to have an answer why. However, feeding current in via pull-ups to unpowered chips and devices is not supposed to be done, it can stress the internal structures of the processor.

Comment: @TypeIA: what hardware change would be needed to avoid a change in the driver. From an architectural standpoint the schematics is very close to that of the CM4io board, but with separate power sources.

Comment: Hard to say without schematics. Does the slave have a reset signal you can route so that it's "pulled out of reset" only when the Raspberry Pi power is stable? Otherwise you need to identify the cause of the spurious edges or other out of spec sequencing and correct that.